# Dealing with the current time in reactive-banana

Tags: haskell, frp, reactive-banana

## How do you deal with the current time in reactive-banana?

Ideally I'd like to have a `Behaviour` which I can "poll" to get the current time.   However, polling `Behaviour`s with `Event`s (via `<@` etc.) gives me the value of the `Behaviour` from the *previous* `Event`, not the current value.  (I realise this is to avoid cyclic definitions which is indeed useful.)

I found `fromPoll` which I thought would help.  `Behaviour`s that are observed from `fromPoll` cannot depend on themselves, thus no cycles can be introduced by observing the behaviour *just before* this `Event` is fired rather than *just after* the previous `Event` fired.

## A digression

In somewhat more formal terms I am suggesting that `Event`s always occur at time *t+* and `Behaviours` are always observed at time *t-* i.e. `Event`s observe behaviours that happen an infinitessimally short time before them.  New values of `Behaviour`s generated by `accumB` and friends would always start from time *t+* so could not be observed by `Event`s which also happen at time *t+*.

Under this proposed semantics `Behaviour`s created by `fromPoll` would be updated just before each `Event` is processed. Other `Behaviour`s would be updated afterwards because they are created by `accumB` and friends.

## My use case

Anyway, that's a significant digression to my main question.  I want to know if there's some way to deal with *current* time (not the time of the *previous* `Event`) in reactive-banana.  My use case is, for example, to keep track of the pings that entities send and if any of them hasn't sent a ping in a particular time interval to signal a warning event.

Of course I can and will fire off events very frequently, so my warnings won't be incorrect by a large amount.  However it does seem to be a wart that they cannot be precise.

What's the right way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your example use case, I think you should be fine if you stay away from `fromPoll`. To explain why, a few clarifications are needed. (Note: in what follows, "stream" refers to an `Event t a`, and "occurrence" to one of the firings which compose them.)

> However, polling Behaviours with Events (via `<@` etc.) gives me the value of the Behaviour from the previous Event, not the current value.

I suppose you are alluding to explanations such as this one, from the docs for [`stepper`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive-banana-0.8.0.2/docs/Reactive-Banana-Combinators.html#v:stepper):

> Note that the smaller-than-sign in the comparision `timex < time` means that the value of the behavior changes "slightly after" the event occurrences. This allows for recursive definitions.

That delay, however, is only with respect to the stream used to define the behaviour (i.e. the one you pass to `stepper`/`accumB`) and any streams that are synchronised with it. For instance, suppose you have two independent streams, `eTick` and `eTock`, and the following network snippet:

```
eIncrement = (+1) <$ eTick
bCount = accumB 0 eIncrement
eCountTick = bCount <@ eTick

eCountTock = bCount <@ eTock
```

`eIncrement` and `eCountTick` are in sync with `eTick`, and so the value observed through `eCountTick` is the "old" value; that is, the value before the synchronised update. From the point of view given by `eCountTock`, however, none of that matters. To an observer using `eCountTock`, there is no delay to speak of, and the value is always the current one.

> Behaviours that are observed from `fromPoll` cannot depend on themselves, thus no cycles can be introduced by observing the behaviour just *before* this Event is fired rather than just *after* the previous Event fired.

We are only concerned with streams synchronised with the one which updates the behaviour. Thus, as far as observed values go "just before the next occurrence" and "just after the previous occurrence" boil down to the same thing. `fromPoll`, however, muddles things quite a bit. It creates a behaviour which is updated whenever *any* occurrence happens in the event network; and so the updates are synchronised with the union of all streams. There is no such thing as a stream independent from a `fromPoll` event, and therefore the observed value will be affected by the delay however we observe it. That being so, `fromPoll` won't work for an application-driving clock, which requires tracking continuous change with some accuracy.

Implicit in all of the above is that [reactive-banana has no built-in notion of time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19704176/2751851). There are only the "logical" time lines within each stream, which can be interwoven by merging streams. So if we want a current time behaviour our best bet is building one from an independent stream. Here is a demo of that approach, which will produce fresh and timely results as far as the precision of `threadDelay` allows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
module Main where

import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Monad
import Data.Time
import Reactive.Banana
import Reactive.Banana.Frameworks

main = do
    let netDesc :: forall t. Frameworks t => Moment t ()
        netDesc = do
            (eTime, fireTime) <- newEvent
            liftIO . forkIO . forever $
                threadDelay (50 * 1000) >> getCurrentTime >>= fireTime
            bTime <- flip stepper eTime <$> liftIO getCurrentTime
            (eTick, fireTick) <- newEvent
            liftIO . forkIO . forever $
                threadDelay (5000 * 1000) >> fireTick ()
            reactimate $ print <$> bTime <@ eTick
    network <- compile netDesc
    actuate network >> threadDelay (52000 * 1000) >> pause network
```

`bTime` is updated through `eTime` each 0.05s; it is observed through `eTick`, a stream independent from `eTime` with occurrences every 5s. You can then use `eTick` and streams derived from it to observe and update your entities. Alternatively, you can combine `bTime` and the entity behaviours in applicative style to get, e.g. behaviours for the latest pings, to be observed with `eTick`.

Having a canonical time behaviour looks like a sound approach in your case; it is conceptually clear and readily generalisable for multiple ticks. In any case, other approaches that you can play with include getting rid of `bTime` and using `eTick` as a low-resolution current time stream (though that seems to make the `threadDelay` innacurcies build up faster), and getting rid of `eTick` by using [`changes`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive-banana-0.8.0.2/docs/Reactive-Banana-Frameworks.html#v:changes) to get a stream of freshly updated values from the behaviour (through that comes with its own quirks and annoyances, as the documentation hints at).

Comment: Ah, so I should have one `Behaviour` for the current time and a completely separate `Behaviour` for ticks.  That makes sense, thanks.  It still seems a shame that the tick can't bring in the current time itself though, but perhaps I am just unaware of the subtleties that causes in FRP!

Comment: @TomEllis In my example there are two independent `Event`s but just one `Behavior`, `bTime`. `eTick` is just a tool for observing other things; there is no observable associated with it in the domain model. If you want to bring the time with the tick (which may be a good enough solution in simple cases) the easiest way is not using a `Behavior` at all; for instance, by removing `bTime` and `eTick` and using `eTime` (with a suitable tick period) directly.

Comment: Ah yes actually I meant to write two separate `Event`s, not `Behaviour`s.